# How to get log unique requests and check their status in Lucee

Tags: http-headers, lucee

I am trying to log specific requests by users to determine if their Lucee request has completed, if it is still running, etc.  The purpose of this is to fire of automated processes on demand and ensure to the end users that the processes is already started so they do not fire off a second process.  I have found the HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID in other searches, but when dumping the CGI variables, it is not listed.  I have set CGI variables to Writable rather than Read Only, but it is still not showing up.  Is it something I must add in IIS, or a setting in Lucee Admin that I am overlooking.  Is there a different way to go about doing this rather than HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question right: Do you want to fire specific procedures or processes, e.g. a fire cfexecute or fire a large file creation that then will run in the background, and be sure the users are not going to retrigger it again, or just log the start of a http request until the page has completed processing (e.g. with onRequestStart until onRequestEnd)? Could you please give more details?

Answer (score 0):

Have yo consider using `<cfflush>`. When Lucee request start you can send partial information to the client informing that the process has started in the server.

Comment: I wanted to say "Have you consider using CFFLUSH".

Comment: You need to use 'code' formatting to display that text. I updated for you.